# Gym's box 2d (openAI) doesn't install successfully (pip error)

Tags: python, machine-learning, box2d, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to do the follow code with OpenAI:

```py
import gym
env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0')
env.reset() 

for _ in range(1000):
 env.render()
 env.step(env.action_space.sample())
```

but it throws the error:

> fn = getattr(mod, attr_name)
>   AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'CarRacing'

And then I try to install box2d by pip install box2d-py throwing this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Junior\Anaconda\envs\gym\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Junior\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w8awn22p\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Junior\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w8awn22p\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Junior\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-netg1nlq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Junior\Anaconda\envs\gym\Include\box2d-py'
         cwd: C:\Users\Junior\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w8awn22p\box2d-py\
    Complete output (16 lines):
    Using setuptools (version 45.2.0.post20200210).
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
    copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
    running build_ext
    building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
    swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
    swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Junior\Anaconda\envs\gym\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Junior\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w8awn22p\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Junior\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w8awn22p\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Junior\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-netg1nlq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Junior\Anaconda\envs\gym\Include\box2d-py' Check the logs for full command output.
```

what I have to do to install it successfully?

Comment: it needs `swig.exe` so probably you need http://www.swig.org/index.php

Comment: Have you tried conda?

Comment: On Mac, simply ```pip install Box2d```   . It works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows support is at present moment experimental ([source](https://github.com/openai/gym#environments)). That being said, on most of the occasions you will get it to work, but some of the functionality could be broken. Proceed with caution.

Here's what could work:

1. Install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/).
2. Start Anaconda command line (it adds `conda` to the PATH).
3. `conda create -c conda-forge -n gymenv swig pip` - create base environment.
4. `conda activate gymenv` - activate it.
5. `pip install Box2D gym` - install base gym with Box2D.
6. (Optional) `pip install gym[all]` - install all components of Gym. You might run into errors.

If you get build errors on missing compilers, install [Visual Studio Built Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16).

Depending on the component you're using, you might need e.g. `pystan`. Activate then the conda environment and install it, i.e. `conda install pystan`.

An alternative could be to try to install Gym directly through conda:

```
conda create -c conda-forge -c powerai -n gymenv gym swig pip pystan
```

This will install `gym` from [powerai channel](https://anaconda.org/powerai/gym). *Might work*, but mind that it's not the latest nor seems to be supported by devs.

Comment: On Mac, simply pip install Box2d . It works for me

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I got it sorted with just installing swig before gym[box2d] no anaconda needed

```
pip3 install swig
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used the `conda` to install Gym's Box2D:

```bash
conda install swig
```

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge gym-box2d
```

and got rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

*(As a windows user)* For me, the solution was to download and install the latest stable version of **Build Tools pour Visual Studio** (2022 currently). Then the `pip install gym[box2d]` worked.